# Android phones use actual density or generalized density for motion of bitmaps in SurfaceView Canvas?

Tags: android, screen

I am developing an Android game, in which a ball (bitmap) translates( is in motion). So I have provided motion equations for the ball. I have checked my app on Samsung galaxy S2 whose actual density is roundly 252 dpi, and It works fine on that. So my question is that Does these motions of bitmaps in surfaceView, depends on actual density of phone( i.e 252 dpi for S2) or generalized density(i.e 240 dpi).

I am confused whether if I run this app on 235 dpi smartphone, So will it have the same performance of motion as it is on Galaxy S2( with 252 dpi) or it would be little slow ?

Any help will be appreciated.