# Android Canvas game supporint multiple screens

Tags: android, canvas

Well, my question is almost the same as this one: [Android phones use actual density or generalized density for motion of bitmaps in SurfaceView Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044824/android-phones-use-actual-density-or-generalized-density-for-motion-of-bitmaps-i)

I'm developing a android game using Canvas, I have images in a single size, and they fit well on my hdpi device and when I run it on lower devices, it's still fitting well, my question is, I don't need them in different sizes?

I'll economize heap memmory if I have smaller images to run in a ldpi device for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing multiple resources will avoid heavy downscaling process, use less memory, etc..

You don't NEED to put them, but it is a good practice.

Comment: That's good to know. it's using a lot of memmory on lower devices, I think this may be the problem right?

Comment: Sound obvious for me, yes, maybe there are other reasons, but of course, loading smaller ressources = smaller heap!

Comment: Nice, thanks. Can you please help me with my other question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240981/android-canvas-image-quality-size-in-mb-interferes-on-heap-memory